# Camera film negative

Tags: word, cipher

[image]

A niece of mine showed me a roll of film negative with various snap shots of rectangles. She said that there is hidden information or a message in that film which could be seen if it is developed with special liquid but also said that I can figure them out anyway. 
What could it be?

Comment: ugh I should've read the actual problem before starting, I assumed this was going to be data hidden in the binary

Comment: Well, I guess you need that special liquid then...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From other answers and from OP's comments, we know:

> - that the rectangles represent the 26 letters of the alphabet;
>
>   that there is a "segment word";
>
>   that the marks show where there are corners in the letter and
>
>   that curves were not shaded.

The rectangles are ...

> ... the top, bottom and side views of the letters as they might appear in a technical drawing. Hidden edges are not shown. Curves are not treated specially, so that the side view of an H and an O look the same. However, there is a hard edge where a straight edge meets a curve, Which normally wouldn't be the case, but which lets us distinguish a D from an O, for example.
>
>  To illustrate:
>
>  [image: part of the film revealed]

The letters on the film are:

> OZSDLCBQPHUJNVTFIMAGERYKXW
>
>  (In the current representation, U and J are the same, as are H and N.)

There is a single word hidden in the letters:

> **IMAGERY**.

Comment: Is there anything to the "liquid" in the clue? A red herring?

Comment: @Forklift-The liquid would turn some area to green as guessed by M Oehm

Answer (score 3):

Word Answer:

> **Fixage**

Within Image:

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iVrt.png

A Google search of 'fixage photographie' (french), returns the following Wiki:
https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixateur

> "a chemical solution used at the end of the development and which
>   completely desensitizes a photographic film or paper"

Comment: How did you get that? Also, why only that part of the film and not another part?

Comment: @boboquack OP had mentioned in a comment on Techidiot's answer, that there was a 'segment word'. I had many different edits of the original image, where I was trying to figure the letters out. In the end, FIX or FIXAGE was the only word that really stood out

Comment: @MalvEarp- X side views has horizontal line at middle . M doesn't have

Answer (score 2):

**Partial answer:**

I'm hoping I'm on the right track, I wish I had time to sit and go through each frame.

> It looks like the lines on the cells are where lines could be made to form letters, some really stand out like that.

Here are a couple of examples:

> [image]  [image]

Maybe this is just from editing:

> The guide holes in the film aren't all in line, could this be a clue or just a case of misalignment when making the image?

If no one makes progress on this I'll be back for a deeper look tomorrow! (EDIT: I've added a few examples above)

Comment: I had come to this same conclusion shortly after having been posted, but couldn't fully decode them, so I've just left the PSD sitting open for the last week. XD

Comment: @TSLF I had also wondered about the misaligned holes. Relevant?

Comment: @ BreakingMyself -almost ..but that is not M on last film segment you posted..find the word

Comment: curves were not shaded and shall be seen like flat..

Comment: I suppose M could be an A. If I get chance I'll go through it frame by frame still and see what could be  missing.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if it's right but worth a try -

Is the message hidden -

> *The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog* and the word is **Pangram**

How?

> There are exactly 26 blocks in there. Each of them is a unique one. Which makes me think of *alphabets* Now, the most common message formed using all 26 alphabets is -
>
>  *The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog*
>
>  This could be the possible message which is nothing but **Pangram**

Comment: On the right track..but word tag dot not allow phrase or sentence/s

Comment: I think the colored lines on the film canister indicates that we should put these colors in the spaces according to the size.

Comment: @Mordechai-no nothing about that, just random alphabet that has a segment  word